# Assign Variables in Loop at Bash

Tags: bash, shell, loops, variables, set

I trying to run some code in bash. But i have to assign or set variables in loop. When i run my .sh, gives the error: No command in line

Below is an example of the codes.

```
#! /bin/bash
newfile="/exp/exp/code"
bool=true
file="/exp/exp/newcode"
for i in {1..10}
do
    declare $bool=false
    $newfield =$file
    $file=$i
done
```

Comment: Remove the '$' on the LEFT hand side of the assignments. And remove any spaces around the '=' signs.

Comment: Btw., you don't need to 'declare' in the loop this way.

Comment: https://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do or achieve, but the fragment in your question should read:

```
#! /bin/bash
newfile="/exp/exp/code"
bool=true
file="/exp/exp/newcode"
for i in {1..10}
do
    bool=false
    newfield=$file
    file=$i
done
```

Comment: Perhaps you should *ask* what they are trying to achieve.